# How to rearrange the items in a map based on another map keys

Tags: java, hashmap

Hi I had a requirement where objects of a map are to arranged
in order of keys of another map.
here is the map

```
Map ObjectMap = new HashMap()
ObjectMap .put(id1,Obj1);
ObjectMap .put(id2,Obj2);
ObjectMap .put(id3,Obj3);
ObjectMap .put(id4,Obj4);
```

Now a rank map decides the order of ids in ObjectMap

```
Map rankedMap = new HashMap()

rankedMap .put(rank1,id3);
rankedMap .put(rank2,id4);
rankedMap .put(rank3,id1);
rankedMap .put(rank4,id2);
```

Now I have to arrange the ObjectMap objects accoding to the rank of each ids like

```
ObjectMap .put(id3,Obj1);
ObjectMap .put(id4,Obj2);
ObjectMap .put(id1,Obj3);
ObjectMap .put(id2,Obj4);
```

`ids` are `Long` objects

`ranks` are `int` objects

Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) The objects in HashMap are not ordered, so arranging them does not have any sense. You should use a list or some kind of linked map (like LinkedHashMap)
2) 'ObjectMap' should not start with an uppercase 'O'
3) what kind of objects are the 'rank' objects?

Comment: To me it looks like some kind of HashMap overuse. Are you sure you need all those Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with TreeMaps and custom Comparators.

Comment: sorry, I miss-looked that you don't want the Obj to remain mapped to the same ID.

Answer (score 2):

The 'rankedMap' should be a linked map, as said above:

```
Map rankedMap = new LinkedHashMap()

rankedMap .put(rank1,id3);
rankedMap .put(rank2,id4);
rankedMap .put(rank3,id1);
rankedMap .put(rank4,id2);
```

next, you can iterate over the ids in the rankedMap to fill the rankedObjectMap, which is also a linkedHashMap: (code not tested)

```
Map rankedObjectMap = new LinkedHashMap();
for(Object id : rankedMap.values()){
  rankedObjectMap.put(id, objectMap.get(id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` has no defined ordering. If you want ordering, and still benefit the O(1) seek time the `HashMap` offers, you might want to use [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), but note that ordering in this map is defined by order of insertions. You will have to take care of it by inserting your elements in order.